# how to delete swarm of ._ files using commandline

Tags: command-line, filenames, rm

I have these files in MAC which have weird `._` character before filenames/folders. Which I want to delete in one shot. Is there a way to do it in commandline?

eg.
`._js`
`._css`
`._image`

if I go into normal image folder. I see another swarm of these files along with the actual files.

Comment: In bash, `rm ._*` <-- Sorcery!

Comment: @ParthianShot Please post answers as answers, not as comments.

Comment: @Gilles Oh, alright...

Comment: Why is my question down voted?

Comment: I guess it's because they think you shouldn't delete them and over than that you can search for the way to easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash, this will delete everything in the current working directory which has the prefix `._`:

```
rm ._*
```

If what you actually wanted to do was change their names to a form without the prefix, you can run:

```
ls ._* | while read line
do
  mv -- "$line" "${line:2}"
done
```

Comment: Note that your answer won't work if filename contains newline, or too many files.

Comment: Note: renaming a `._file` to `file` will overwrite the data fork in AppleDoubleFormat files, rendering the file unless.

Comment: @cuonglm `if filename contains newline` True. Although, thankfully, I've never run into code in the wild which does that (excepting things I've intentionally written for fun; `touch $'\n'`).